# Strange error running a simple groovy script using Micronaut DI and Vertx

Tags: groovy, dependency-injection, vert.x, micronaut

I have a project which is using Vertx and Micronaut DI

however something in this process breaks a simple capability in groovy of coercing a map to an interface

I have created a simple script like this.  The same script in a simple groovy only project works just fine.

Has anyone else seen anything like this and what if anything needs to be fixed.  I don't understand the error as the script itself isn't using  DI or Vertx.  I am assuming its something going wrong with Micronaut pre processors ?

```
package ioc

def map
map = [
        i: 10,
        hasNext: { map.i > 0 },
        next: { map.i-- },
]
def iter = map as Iterator
iter.each {println it}
```

Which when i run it generates the following error.

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/codegen/annotations/DataObject
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/codegen/annotations/DataObject
    at io.vertx.lang.groovy.VertxExtensionModule.asType(VertxExtensionModule.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at ioc.coerce.run(coerce.groovy:9)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vertx.codegen.annotations.DataObject
    ... 8 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Has any one seen anything like this and were able to fix it?  Its a bit weird by itself.

Comment: There's not enough info here to diagnose.  Do you have a simple reproducible example, including how you are building and running your code?

Comment: project is here https://github.com/woodmawa/vertx-assessment.  I have added the script in standalone groovy script - nothing else in it which you can find here https://github.com/woodmawa/vertx-assessment/blob/master/src/main/groovy/scripts/mapCoercionScript.groovy

Comment: this works fin an an new empty project, no vertx, and no micronaut dependencies.  To work around this i actually had to create a class that implemented the interface (Flow.Subscriber from Java 9) and had to use that instead

Comment: code is built with gradle, and i run the script from within the IDE

Comment: I'm struggling to see why having scripts in `src/main/groovy` is a good idea 

Comment: I just do that when i'm doing some exploratory play pen work - once i'm happy with approach , i go back the rest of the project and start writing tests etc

Comment: sometimes just running a quick script in the IDE with debug is helpful for me at least - this is not a production project at this point